# Tornado: get_argument -- should I escape the input myself?

Tags: python, database, sql-injection, tornado

I'm running a Tornado web server for a single page application. The client is POSTing to the server and I'm using `tornado.web.RequestHandler.get_argument()` to get the input.

When testing, I can't seem to force an SQL injection bug. It looks like `get_argument()` somehow escapes the input. When doing a POST from a login-form (username + password) I've tried all sorts of tricks to force a simple SQL injection but to no avail.

EDIT2:

HAH! I managed to do an SQL injection at last :D I URL-escaped some of the input and I could see the injected SQL statement go all the way to the DB module.
The query I generate from the login-form does not get committed, as it's just supposed to be a SELECT statement - so I couldn't actually alter the database.

**If the query never gets committed and the output of the whole query (including the injected) is hidden, what kind of damage can be done ?**

For instance if the query is supposed to be, say `SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserID='USERNAME' AND Password='PASSWORD';` but the input for username has an INSERT injected, so `USERNAME` becomes `USERNAME'; INSERT INTO Users (UserID, Password) VALUES ('hacker', 'hacked'); --` we end up with:

`SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserID='USERNAME'; INSERT INTO Users (UserID, Password) VALUES ('hacker', 'hacked'); --' AND Password='PASSWORD';`

I am aware of the dangers of SQL injections in general, I'm just curious regarding this detail. I'm also aware I should hash and salt passwords, the code above is a simplification for the sake of the example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tornado only escapes the strings in the templates to avoid HTML issues.  If you're just doing something like `print self.get_argument('ihack')` you'll get the raw string that is sent.

You should using MySQLdb with injection prevention:

```
 cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE email = %s", email)
```

Rather than:

```
 cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE email = %s" % email)   # BAD!
```

This will protected your SQL just like the templates protect your HTML.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll see if I can migrate to parameterized queries somewhere down the road. And oh, I've added another edit to my question.

Comment: that's a classic, but I don't think it's possible if you do not commit the query. I do acknowledge your point, I'm merely curious about this detail. As far as I can tell from reading the docs, a transaction just rolls back if you don't commit.

Comment: Lets see ... ``email = foo"; drop table users; commit;``  the MySQLdb.commit() just sends the SQL command "commit".

Comment: Thanks for your help! I've been struggling a lot to get the injection to work :) I'd completely overlooked manually comitting the statement